# SVG/PNG not showing up in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg, png

My svg, same with png, image is not showing up in the newest version of Mozilla Firefox.

I am trying to display it in a way smaller div (`#navigationbar` on top of the page).

Although, **the only thing showing up is the alternate text.**
The permissions are correct and apache-user can read the picture, the path to the svg/png in the HTML is correct as well.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="navigationBar">
  <img src="pictures/logo.svg" alt="mm World" />
  <a href="mmHome.html" class="navigationButtonSelected">Home</a><a href="ubuntuOverview.html" class="navigationButton">Ubuntu</a>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <h1>Welcome to mm</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#navigationBar {
    background-color:#660099;
    text-align:center;
    }

.navigationButton {
    background-color:transparent;
    border-bottom:2px solid transparent;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:16px 31px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}

.navigationButtonSelected {
    background-color:transparent;
    border-bottom:2px solid #18ab29;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:16px 31px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}

.navigationButton:hover {
    border-bottom:2px solid #18ab29;
}

.navigationButton.navigationButtonSelected:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

Comment: Eleven bytes per pixel? Have you considered saving it as a PNG instead?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Firstly i did try it with a png.. with the same result. So that is not causing the problem and i prefer loss-free scalability over storage/0.01ms longer to download

Comment: If the same happens with png then this isn't an SVG issue and you should retitle, reword and retag the question.

Comment: @RobertLongson Good point! Edited the question. Maybe you have an idea?

Comment: What is the mime-type of the images?

Comment: @RobertLongson It is only one and in case of the svg i would say image/svg+xml but the img-tag does not take an type-attribute

Comment: The mime type comes from the server and is not set in markup. It's part of the http response.

Comment: Does it help to use "./pictures/logo.svg" instead of "pictures/logo.svg"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the image was world readable I had to switch the owner of the file from root to `www-data(default apache user)` on my `Ubuntu Server 14.04`:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /pathtoimage/logo.svg
```

afterwards I recommend setting file-access to `read-only` for owner, owner-group and everybody:

```
sudo chmod 444 /pathtoimage/logo.svg
```

that way I make sure that even when apache got compromised, the hacker can only read logo.svg file.

**There was no problem with the code/path. It was/is a strange permission problem of the server!**

If somebody knows why I had to change the user even that it already was world-readable please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

Try add a MIME Type SVG (image/svg+xml) to your server (IIS, Apache...) and try open your SVG file with Inkscape or the text editor to confirm is a SVG file format with the first line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Your CSS and HTML code work for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#navigationBar {
    background-color:#660099;
    text-align:center;
    }

.navigationButton {
    background-color:transparent;
    border-bottom:2px solid transparent;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:16px 31px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}

.navigationButtonSelected {
    background-color:transparent;
    border-bottom:2px solid #18ab29;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:16px 31px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}

.navigationButton:hover {
    border-bottom:2px solid #18ab29;
}

.navigationButton.navigationButtonSelected:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="navigationBar">
  <img src="http://blackicemedia.com/presentations/2013-02-hires/img/awesome_tiger.svg" alt="mm World" width="100" height="100"/>
  <a href="mmHome.html" class="navigationButtonSelected">Home</a><a href="ubuntuOverview.html" class="navigationButton">Ubuntu</a>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <h1>Welcome to mm</h1>
</div>

</body>
```